# AWS S3 NoSuchBucket Exception Not Caught in Rescue Clause

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get a bucket in Ruby using the AWS SDK, and trying to catch a NoSuchBucket error. Problem is, my rescue block is not catching the error, and so my app crashes. Here is the relevant code:

```
begin
    b = s3.buckets[bucket_name]

rescue AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchBucket
    puts Invalid bucket name.
    exit 1
end
```

and the error message is:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.5.6/lib/aws/core/client.rb:277:in
`return_or_raise': The specified bucket does not exist (AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchBucket)
```

Am I just making a stupid beginner syntax error, or is there a bug in the AWS code that's not actually throwing the error? I've also tried catching all errors and still no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
```

Doesn't actually make any requests and won't ever through exceptions like `NoSuchBucket`.

It just returns a bucket object that knows what its name is. A request only happens when you actually try to do something with the bucket (list its contents, add a file to it) and it is at this point that `NoSuchBucket` is raised. This is outside of your `begin` block and so your `rescue` doesn't handle it. If you need to rescue that exception, you need to be putting your begin/rescue around the places that you actually use the bucket.

If you are just trying to validate that it actually exists you could do something like

```
s3.buckets[bucket_name].exists?
```

Comment: Just a note, the `.exists?` didn't work. Neither using `[]` to grab the bucket or `[]` to grab the objects form the bucket throw the Error, only trying to write to an object does. Thanks for confirming where the error actually gets thrown.